# grotty, troff, nroff, groff, preconv... are these normal?

Tags: 14.04

I'm checking commands that are being executed and I noticed these commands have been run. Are these normal commands and what are they doing?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are a normal part of any Linux system.

[groff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groff_%28software%29) is a text formatting program that is used to format and display man pages.

`grotty`, `troff`, `nroff` and `preconv` are helper programs used by `groff`. See their man pages (`man grotty`, `man troff`, ...) if you want to know the details.